# Dispose provider in Widget Test

Tags: flutter, flutter-test, flutter-provider

I'm performing some widget tests on my Flutter app with flutter_test.
It basically works fine except when my testing widget is a Consumer.

Here, I basically have a DeviceProvider objects that wraps an object into a ChangeNotifier so that updates are correctly propagated to consumers.

To be able to use it with a WidgetTester, I put my Consumer widget inside a ChangeNotifierProvider that intantiates a DeviceProvider.

```
_pumpTestableWidgetWithProvider(WidgetTester tester, Widget widget) async {
    DeviceProvider device = DeviceProvider(Device());
    await tester.pumpWidget(ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (context) => device,
        child: MaterialApp(home: widget)));
    return device;
}
```

Then, I use the WidgetTester I have just pumped and check whether some text fields are in them.

```
testWidgets("Infos - default device infos", (WidgetTester tester) async {
    DeviceProvider device = await _pumpTestableWidgetWithProvider(
        tester, DeviceInfos());
    expect(find.text("Battery state: "), findsOneWidget);
});
```

It returns with an error telling me that 'A Timer is still pending even after the widget tree was disposed'. Looking at the log, this timer corresponds to a _FakeTimer created with the DeviceProvider. I thus tried to manually dispose the provider by using

```
device.dispose();
```

But now, I have an error telling me that 'A DeviceProvider was used after being disposed.'

Does anyone have a solution for me ?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. Trying to test a widget that uses a provider, and I'm getting this error on the second test...

Comment: Could you share a full snippet necessary to reproduce the error?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it using a different constructor for the changeNotifierProvider on the tests:

```
Widget buildWidget() {
      return ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
        value: locator<TaNaLeiProvider>(),
        child: MaterialApp(
          home: Scaffold(
            body: SizedBox(
              width: 640,
              child: DrawerTaNaLei(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
```

Note that I'm using ChangeNotifierProvider.value instead of create.
I'm also using getIt to create singletons on my app.

`locator.registerLazySingleton<TaNaLeiProvider>(() => TaNaLeiProvider());`

Hope that helps!

Comment: I am having similar problems. I used Stacked and GetIt and my widget test is failing? Can you provide any sample code??

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the problem, I had an actual timer running inside my DeviceProvider and this timer was not canceled.

Thanks for your support !